# C++ Structure alignment

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct, padding

I am using Visual C++ on Windows. I have following structs:

```
struct Vector3
{
   float x, y, z;
};

struct Vector4
{
   union
   {
      __m128 _xmm;
      struct
      {
         float x, y, z, w;
      };
   };
}
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct Vertex
{
   Vector3 Position;
   Vector4 Color;
}
#pragma pack(pop)
```

I need to prevent padding in `struct Vertex`, but this code does not work(`sizeof(Vertex) == 32`, I want `sizeof(Vertex) == 28`) and I have zero ideas how to fix it.

Comment: 1) Don't used packed, it only leads to slower code. If you have unaligned data then copy to/from aligned structures and work with those. 2) pack isn't recursive, you need to pack `Vector3` and `Vector4`.

Comment: Change **Vertex** to `struct Vertex { std::byte Position[12]; std::byte Color[16]; };` and then use `memcpy` to transfer the bytes to/from a `Vector3` and `Vector4`. Consider helpful getters/setters to do that part.

Comment: `__m128` has an alignment requirement of 16 so `16 + 12 = 28` but the next (imagine an array of `Vertex`) `__m128` needs to be on a 16 byte boundary which is 32.

Comment: Once you include a member of `__m128` type - which is automatically aligned on a 16-byte boundary - then nothing you can do will reduce the alignment of the containing structure. You can play around with `#pragma pack()` and `alignas()` until the proverbial bovine females return to their domicile, but it won't make a jot of difference.